# Duplicate entry for key "PRIMARY" in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

**Query for creating table :**

> ```
> create table if not exists person ( 
> roll_no int(4) AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
> name varchar(25),  
> city varchar(25));
> ```

**Query to set start number for auto-increment primary key :**

> `alter table person auto_increment = 1;`

**Query to insert data :**

> ```
> insert into person (name,city) values("Maxwell", "Pune");
> insert into person (name,city) values("Baldwin", "Bengaluru");
> insert into person (name,city) values("Novartis", "Paris");
> insert into person (name,city) values("Shaun", "Mumbai");
> insert into person (name,city) values("Beckham", "Toronto");
> insert into person (name,city) values("Ashish", "Bengaluru");
> insert into person (name,city) values("David", "Paris");
> insert into person (name,city) values("PK", "London");
> insert into person (name,city) values("Chris", "Bengaluru");
> insert into person (name,city) values("Aston", "Mumbai");
> ```

**Query to delete the row :**

> `delete from person where roll_no=5;`

**Table structure after deleting the row:**

> ```
> roll_no      name       city
> 1            Maxwell    Pune
> 2            Baldwin    Bengaluru
> 3            Novartis   Paris
> 4            Shaun      Mumbai
> 6            Ashish     Bengaluru
> 7            David      Paris
> 8            PK         London
> 9            Chris      Bengaluru
> 10           Aston      Mumbai
> ```

Now, while looking to reinstate the deleted row, the compiler is **throwing error** as ***" `Duplicate entry '5' for key 'PRIMARY'` "***

**Query used to re-instate the deleted row.**

> ```
> update person set roll_no = roll_no + 1 where roll_no >=4 order by roll_no desc;
> insert into person (roll_no, name, city) VALUES (5, "Beckham", "Toronto");
> ```

**What could be the possible reason for this issue ?** **Any inputs would be highly recommended.**

Comment: just remove the update statement..

Comment: What does the table look like AFTER the UPDATE but BEFORE the INSERT? See? Quite simple really.

Comment: @amdixon - Beautiful...that solved the issue, however still clueless why update query was posing a problem ? Could you explain a bit ?

Comment: @amdixon - Is there a way you can compile the above comments as an answer so that I could mark it as an accepted answer & thereby close the thread..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restore the deleted row, it is only necessary to perform the insert statement. Can simply remove the update statement and use following :

**query**

```
insert into person (roll_no, name, city) VALUES (5, "Beckham", "Toronto");
```

Answer (score 1):

So simple, in your update query you are making 4 become 5 and then trying to insert 5. That's why its a duplicate.